# Django user profile No Profile matches the given query at

Tags: django, python-3.x

when user signup, it will create an user profile at the time.

column id in account.user table has FK with created_by in profile table

**Register/views.py**

```
class RegisterFormView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'home/register.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    regis_form = RegisterForm()
    return self.render_to_response({
        'base_url' : settings.BASE_URL,
        'regis': regis_form,

    })

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        regis_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if regis_form.is_valid():
            user = regis_form.save()
            user.full_name = regis_form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
            user.email = regis_form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            user.phone_number = regis_form.cleaned_data.get("phone_number")
            user.set_password(regis_form.cleaned_data.get("password"))
            password = regis_form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            profile = Profile.objects.create(created_by=user)
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(phone_number=user.phone_number, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Register success")
            return redirect(reverse("home:register-success"))
        else:
            regis_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    return self.render_to_response({
        'base_url' : settings.BASE_URL,
        'regis': regis_form,
    })
```

**Profile/views.py**

```
class ProfileView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'accounts/index.html'

def get(self, request, user_id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=user_id)
    return self.render_to_response({
        'base_url' : settings.BASE_URL,
        'data' : data,
    })
```

**Profile/urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

**Template/base.html**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'profile:profile' user.id %}">Profile</a>
```

register and create profile has succeess

but I cannot access user profile page, i have an error

> No Profile matches the given query.

Edit :

**Profile/models.py**

```
class Profile(BaseModelUnique):
type = models.ManyToManyField(UserType, blank=True)
country = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=constant.COUNTRY_CHOICES, 
                                            blank=True, null=True)
gender = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=constant.GENDER_CHOICES,
                                                         default=3)
bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
background_cover = models.ImageField(
    storage = storage.USER_COVER_STORAGE,
    max_length=300,
    blank = True,
    null = True
)
avatar = models.ImageField(
    storage = storage.USER_AVATAR_STORAGE,
    max_length=300,
    blank = True,
    null = True
)

def __str__(self):
    return self.owned_by.nick_name
```

**User/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
"""
Users within the Django authentication system are represented by this
model.

Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
"""

def __str__(self):
    return self.nick_name

def get_profile(self):
    from core.structures.account.models import Profile
    return Profile.objects.filter(created_by=self).first()

class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
    swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
    unique_together = ('phone_number', 'nick_name')

class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
id62 = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20,
    help_text=_('Required. 20 characters or fewer. digits only.'),
)

full_name = models.CharField(_('full name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
nick_name = models.CharField(_('nick name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(
    _('staff status'),
    default=False,
    help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
)
is_active = models.BooleanField(
    _('active'),
    default=True,
    help_text=_(
        'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
        'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
    ),
)
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

objects = UserManager()

EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('user')
    verbose_name_plural = _('users')
    abstract = True
```

Comment: can you please share the code for `models.py`?.It would be easier for us to understand the model structure.

Comment: @RajanSharma yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `OnetoOneField` Relation in `User` and `Profile` Model so you the using wrong `user.id` to access profile.

Use `{% url 'profile:profile' user.profile.id %}` **Profile ID** not **User ID**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'profile:profile' user.profile.id %}">Profile</a>
```